# PhpStorm: Change SCSS File Watcher predefined settings

Tags: sass, phpstorm, webstorm

In PhpStorm 2016.3.2, if you open a `.scss` file, a file watcher will be added with default settings:

[image: Default settings]

How can I modify these settings global?

[image: Modified settings]

If I start a new project, the file watcher will be added with the new modified settings?

Comment: Feature now implemented: 2018.2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All file watchers are configured on project level, there is no way to modify watchers globally. However you can use export/import functionality to export your watcher settings (see 'Import' and 'Export' buttons in Settings | Tools | File Watchers)

Related feature requests: [WEB-8414](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8414), [WEB-12478](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12478).

Comment: Thanks!
I hope they will implement this feature.